# How to select all options in a select box without having the scrolling effect in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

So, my scenario is as a follows: I have a select element with a bunch of options inside it. I also have a check box which allows the user to select/deselect all options. The problem is that in Internet Explorer the whole select box is scrolled when I try to select all options within it from code. I use this code:

```
$option.attr("selected", "selected");
```

How can I avoid this scrolling effect? I would like to have all of the options selected but without any delay and this strange effect.

Comment: What do you mean by scrolled.

Comment: And how exactly does one select all options in a select input element? would'nt that sort of defeat the purpose? If it has the multiple attribute, you should say so in your question, and give us an example of how you do this. As a sidenote, `.prop('selected', true)` would be the correct method for setting the selected property with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select onMouseWheel="return false;">
```

Hope this will do the trick for you.